# Error when using one hot vectors as labels for training

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, kaggle

I am working on a binary classification problem (the infamous Titanic example on Kaggle), and I made a MLP network with an **output layer of size 2 and a softmax activation**. I was using a label vector of shape (number_of_example, ) and it was working (i.e not giving any error), but I realized that it should actually not work. Indeed, how can labels being 0 or 1 be compared to softmax vector ? i.e if one example has label **1** (i.e "survived") and the network outputs **(0.21 0.79)** how can theses two values be used to compute the loss ?

So, I replaced the y vector by its one-shot vector equivalent but then I have this error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [10,2] and labels shape [20]

```
titanic_all = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aymeric75/IA/master/train.csv")
titanic_all = titanic_all.replace({'male': 1, 'female': 0})


features = ["Age", "Fare", "Sex", "Pclass", "SibSp"]
X = titanic_all[features].copy()
y = titanic_all.pop('Survived')

print(y.shape)

# Making labels, one hot vectors (so they can be compared with the output layer (2 nodes))
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)

Xtrans = imputer(X, 'ascending', 10)

train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(Xtrans, y, random_state=1)




##################
# Model construct
##################


norm1 = preprocessing.Normalization()
norm1.adapt(np.array(train_X))
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(5,))
x = norm1(inputs)


for i in range(15):
    x = layers.Dense(units=64, activation="relu")(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])



##################
# Model training
##################

history = model.fit(
    train_X,
    train_y,
    #validation_split=0.1,
    batch_size=10,
    epochs=20
)
```

You can find the code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pwYUGS7o9ChgPum2Hp16FlDJit1pftQS?usp=sharing) and modify it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: remove `to_categorical`, use 1 final dense neuron and a sigmoid activation, and use `"binary_crossentropy"`. there's no point in encoding a binary task

Comment: @NicolasGervais thanks ! so by using sigmoid activation, if the value if below 0.5 it will mean that predicted value is 0 I guess ?

Comment: Yes exactly you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your labels are one-hot - then you have to use `categorical_crossentropy`:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

See here: https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class

Comment: Thank you, but could you tell me why *sparse_categorical_crossentropy* will not work in my case ?

Comment: If you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` - then your labels should be integers not one-hot